# How to "Smart Update" an entry based on provided data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-update

Is it possible to write an SQL `UPDATE` that only changes columns if data is actually provided?

Let's say I'm updating a post. A `post` has an `id`, `author`, `title` and `text`. When updating a post, either or both of `title` and `text` can change.
Is there an SQL query which can dynamically change the `UPDATE` based on the provided data? It would maybe look something like this in Nodejs pg:

```
const result = await pgClient.query("UPDATE post SET title = $1, text = $2 WHERE userId = $3", 
                                    ["new title", undefined, "12345"]);
```

with an additional clause saying something like "if undefined, do not update."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`COALESCE()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```sql
UPDATE post
SET    title = COALESCE($1, title)
     , text  = COALESCE($2, text)
WHERE  userId = $3
AND   (title <> $1 OR text <> $2);
```

Plus, add an additional `WHERE` clause to skip updates that would not change anything (but cost the same).
In your case at least one of the non-null parameters must actually differ to have an impact.
If columns themselves can be `NULL`, use instead:

```
...
AND   ($1 IS NOT NULL AND title IS DISTINCT FROM $1
    OR $2 IS NOT NULL AND text IS DISTINCT FROM $2);
```

See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for helping me learn!

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this:

```
UPDATE  post
SET title = CASE WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN title ELSE $1 END
....
```

Comment: Thanks Z, that was pretty much it. I was getting the error "could not determine data type of patameter." So I found on this other post which says that you need to cast the variable to what it is supposed to be. So in this case, replace the $1 with $1::TEXT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089400/postgres-sql-could-not-determine-data-type-of-parameter-by-hibernate. Thanks again!