# Springboot Date could not determine data type of parameter

Tags: java, jquery, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

This is my Employee class :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="national_id")
    private String nationalId;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;

    private Integer salary;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

    private String office;

    private String department;
```

This is my repository class :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository <Employee,Integer>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Employee> {

@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("Select e FROM Employee e  "  +
            "where " +
            " (:startDate is NULL or e.startDate > :startDate) " +
            " AND " +
            " (:salary is NULL or e.salary > :salary) ")
    List<Employee> searchEmployees(@Param(value = "startDate") Date startDate, @Param(value = "salary") Integer salary);
```

When I try to run this query I get this error : could not determine data type of parameter $1

I think it's because of postgreSQL.On the one side, there is the timestamp and on the other side the timestamptz with timezone information.

What can I do for this problem?

Comment: `:startDate is NULL` - do you not mean `e.startDate is NULL` ?

Comment: I think this answer also applies to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64223435/19032206